# How can to associate dimnames of array and data frame index-values in R?

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe, for-loop

I have the array `A`

```
A
,,A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  3     7    8
[2,]  4     11   9
[3,]  2     12   4.3

,,B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  31    7    8
[2,]  4.2   4   9.5
[3,]  1     1    7

,,C
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  4    71    8.3
[2,]  4    41    9 
[3,]  11   0     73

,,D
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  7    7    8.3
[2,]  3    4.1    9 
[3,]  1    0.5    73

 dim(A)
3 3 4
dimnames(A)[3]
A   B    C   D
```

and I have the `data.frame` `df`

```
df

 X  Y   Z
 2  1   A
 3  2   D
```

I would like to put in a new column of df, the values of array A, based on `df` index-values X(row for the array), Y(column for the array) and third dimension Z, let's say, my aspect result is:

```
df

 X  Y   Z  Res
 2  1   A  4    # Res is the value of array A in A[2,1,"A"]
 3  2   D  0.5  # Res is the value of array A in A[3,2,"D"]
```

I tried this code:

```
df$Res <- NA
 if (df$Z == dimnames(A)[3]){
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){ 
   df[i,4] <- A[df[i,1],df[i,2],df[i,3]]
 }
}
```

But it'doesn't work well...
Any idea to associate the dimnames of third dimension array and data frame index-value?

P.S. This is a simple example. My true array is:

```
dim(A)
    137  93  227
```

and

```
dim(df)
6080 3
```

P.S.2 I prefer to don't use `merge` or other type of similar code for allocation problem

Comment: Have you tried `df$Res <- A[df$X, df$Y, df$Z]` ?

Comment: In the `loop`?? or directly? I wrote that my true df and array is very big and I prefer an automatic way, you know?

Comment: Just as it is - you don't need a loop.

Comment: Ok, but it's impossibile for my TRUE array and df, that are very big! I need an automatic code that couple my index-df-values and third array dimension

Comment: @Andrew Gustar ..I tried but R tell me: `Error in ......  subscript out of bounds` ...

Comment: Another way would be `df$ref <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) A[df$Z[i],df$Z[i],df$Z[i]])` - this is just another loop, but it will be faster than a `for` loop.

Comment: You mean : `df$ref <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) A[df$X[i], df$Y[i], df$Z[i]])` true?

Comment: Sorry - yes, well spotted!